# Scroll automático na saída do browser

Tags: php, html

Eu tenho um script em php que retorna muitos dados na tela, mas o scroll sempre fica ao início dela assim que eu tenho que apertar o botão fin do teclado o tempo todo até que o script terminar.

Eu tenho achado que é possível fazer o scroll automático com códigos Javascript, mas eu não quero usar javascript no meu código.

Será que é possível fazer isso só com php e html?

Comment: Por qué os downvotes?

Comment: É preciso mesmo usar javascript, porque isso vai ser executado no navegador e não no servidor (php). (não fui eu que dei downvote)

Answer (score 1):

Como os dados estão no client, você precisa fazer isso com JavaScript. 
Você tem outras opções:

- Paginação (exibir menos registros);
- Ordenação inversa, desta forma os itens que estariam no rodapé ficam no topo (funciona com itens que seguem uma ordem cronológica e vc quer os mais recentes primeiro, como clientes de e-mail fazem);